# Sharepoint 2010 - Redirect to library item's default edit page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I want to programmatically upoad a document to a Sharepoint library.
After uploading I want to redirect the user to the Edit Page (OOB or custom) associated with the new library item.

How do I know where to redirect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some examples here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/2be88c8b-812b-4574-8c2c-965cedd2f199/

```
// Edit form full url
string.Format("{0}{1}?ID={2}", item.Web.Url, item.ParentList.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM].ServerRelativeUrl, item.ID);

// Edit form relative url
string.Format("{0}?ID={1}", item.ParentList.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM].ServerRelativeUrl, item.ID);
```